# Use courier font in ALL text

Tags: lyx, texmaker

I want to apply the courier font to ALL text in my LyX and Texmaker files, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\ttdefault}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!! Exactly!! It works but the text does not appear justified, every line of the text goes out of the margins

Comment: @Alex Yes, of course. That is because Courier is a monospaced font, i.e. we can't control the width of the spaces.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much @JouleV!!

Comment: @Alex You're welcome!